# What is the less ductile and thinnest wire material?

Tags: materials, wire

I'm looking for a very very thin wire that does not bend easily. Which kind of material should I look for? The thinnest the wire the better but copper [can be found](https://imall.com/product/50m-0.01mm-Insulating-Copper-Wire-BGA-Motherboard-Fingerprint-Maintenance-Fly-Line-Solder-for-iPhone/banggood.com/1369196/530-225138/en) in a very thin format (0.01mm) but it bends with very few force applied to it.

What is the least ductile and thinnest wire material I can buy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Less ductile than what? There are tables of values so all you need to do is look.

Comment: The least ductile and I mentioned wired material meaning a material that is already being produced and can be purchased. I have looked around before asking but haven't find an answer

Comment: Here there is a list of multiple types of wire http://fsgsbxg.com/Eng_Wire/ which one is the less ductile of them for the thinnest diameter one?

Comment: Do you mean wire with the highest stiffness ( modulus of elasticity?).

Comment: @blacksmith37 yes that's what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For microscopic electrical probe pins, gold-plated *tungsten* is used because its stiffness modulus is large- which provides best resistance against buckling under compressive stress.

Comment: Or you can do the reverse: take fine gold wire and plate it with a stiff metal like chromium.

Comment: Tungsten is the stiffest metal available. If a length of 7 in. is useful . look up TIG welding electrodes , as I remember they are cold worked . About your only choice unless you work for NASA.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!